# How to search for specific words in column and return it to its same row but another cell?

Tags: vba, excel

I've returned a G3 and H3 value to M3 and N3 cell as result.
What I want is to find only 1 specific word from cell(J3) like "chocolate" and return it to Cell(M3)
Is there a way to write an Excel macro to find those specific words listed in Column(G) in Column(J) and if Column(J) contains those specific words the macro returns only the specific word to Column(M) to the same row it was found. (but another cell, like M3 on the screenshot)
[image: Excel Macro Screenshot]

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim score1 As String, score2 As Integer, result1 As String, result2 As String

score1 = Range("G3").Value
score2 = Range("H3").Value

If score1 = "chocolate" Then
result1 = "chocolate"
result2 = "4"
Else
result1 = "" And result2 = ""
End If

Range("M3").Value = result1
Range("N3").Value = result2

End Sub
```

It's working with Range(Only One Cell).
But how can I search for the specific words listed in Columns("G3:G7") to be found in Column("J:J") and when it is found return the specific word to Column("M") to the same row it was found.
So I can press OK! CommandButton and if Column("J:J") contains any words in Column("G:G") the "found" exact word from Column("G:G") will be inserted to Column("M:M") to the same row where it was found.

I've tried with simple functions as:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($G$3;"*"&A:A&"*"));"chocolate";IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($G$4;"*"&A:A&"*"));"muffin";IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($G$5;"*"&A:A&"*"));"lemon";IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($G$6;"*"&A:A&"*"));"monkey";IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($G$7;"*"&A:A&"*"));"baby")))))
```

and:

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(D3;"*"&A3&"*";A3));B3;"")
```

It's working as you can see below but macro would be easier.
[image: Not macro but working]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edited after OP's clarifications

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim words As Variant
    Dim word As String, number As Long

    words = Range("H3", Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp)).value

    For Each cell In Range("J3", Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
        If FindWord(cell.value, words, word, number) Then
            cell.Offset(, 3).Resize(, 2).value = Array(word, number)
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Function FindWord(sentence As String, words As Variant, returnedWord As String, returnedNumber As Long) As Boolean
    Dim iWord As Long
    Dim word As String

    For iWord = LBound(words, 1) To UBound(words, 1)
        word = CStr(words(iWord, 1))
        If InStr(sentence, word) Then
            FindWord = True
            returnedWord = word
            returnedNumber = CLng(words(iWord, 2))
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: @GálTamás, did you get through it?

Comment: Wow thanks, it's really good but what if I have like 3215 specific words in column("G:G") and only few sentences in column("J:J") contains specific words from column(G), how can I edit your code to refresh it for column("M:N") ?

Comment: I don't get you. The code considers as many "sentences" as there are in columns "J" from cell J3 downwards and as many "words" as there are in columns "G" from cell G3 downwards. So what's the issue?

Comment: If any specific words are written in column(G) and only if column(J) contains this specific word wrapped around in a sentence then I want to display the specific word I've listed in column(G) to be inserted to column(M) with the numbers ofc.
It only works if I write a specific word in column(G) and use this specific word in column(J) but in the same row, only then will be displayed the specific word result in column(M). Column(G) will have a lot of specific words and I want to check if any of those words can be found in column(J) then make it appear in column(M) in the same row.

Comment: So what I mean is there will be random sentences in column(J) and only a few will contains specific words from column(G).
For example I write "lemon" in "G8" and the number is the same "2" in "H8" cell, I fill "J8" with something like "The lemon is red." and the result should be "M8" showing "lemon", "N8" showing "2".

Comment: I uploaded a picture about the problem: [link](http://imgur.com/CoF9fym)

Comment: when considering the first "lemon" (cell G5) the code searches column J for any occurrence of "lemon" and finds it at cell J5, so it writes "lemon" and "2" at cells  M5:N5. the 2nd time around for "lemon" it acts the same. How to differentiate the row to write in? which is the criteria by which choosing the "right" sentence?

Comment: I've checked with G8 filled with "blue", H8 filled with "5" and J8 filled with "The lemon is blue." Result will be displayed in M8 with "blue" and N8 with "5". So it's perfect, but when I use any words from G3:G7 it wont work. Why cant I use those words again?

Comment: you can use words again, but the behavior is the one I wrote in my previous comment. and the question stays the same: how to choose the "right" sentence between many that match?

Comment: I have a list with 2000-2300 specific words and I have specific sentences too which contains almost all the specific words I have the list of.
For example I have 10 sentences and almost all of them contains a specific word from G column. Macro should first check the sentences in column J and if it has one of the specific word from G column it should insert it to column M with the associated number from column H. If the sentence doesn't contain words from column G then it should stay empty. If that is the question. I'm sorry I'm new to excel vba. I guess the macro is checking going row by row.

Comment: I have only 1 issue ---> [link]http://imgur.com/V3K79Ij
What if I have 4 exact words to work with (G3;G4;G5;G6) associated with numbers in H3:H4:H5:H6 and I would like to check macro column(J) for these words as in the screenshot J7;J8;J9 contains specific words from column(G) and want to make it insert them to column(M) and (N) to the same row it was found? I'm sorry for having a lot of questions.